# How to get the primary key of a table in sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have the following code which should be able to get the primary key in a table

```
public List<string> GetPrimaryKeysForTable(string tableName)
    {
        List<String> retVal = new List<string>();
        SqlCommand command = connector.GetCommand("sp_pkeys");
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table_name", typeof(SqlChars)).Value = tableName;
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            retVal.Add(reader[3].ToString());
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

I have a table called `Users` in my database. When I pass `Users` in as my parameter, the reader returns no results. Any idea why this might be failing to return my primary keys?

Comment: Are you sure that you are executing the command against the database which contains the `Users` table (and not the `master` database, for example)?

Comment: Have you tried "exec sp_pkeys Users" from query analyzer?

Comment: Hi, are you getting the right value in this line: retVal.Add(reader[3].ToString());? You can also specify the column name instead of its number. This way you could do something like: retVal.Add(reader["key"].ToString()); and it would be easier to tell if you are trying to get the right column value.

Comment: Interesting, I just tried it, and seems to not work? I just assumed the stored procedure would work. I tried it with a qualified schema as well... still no luck. The table definitely exists though.

Comment: @Komyg Thanks for the comment. I am actually not even able to get inside the loop there. The reader returns me no results from the stored procedure.

Comment: While in debug mode, if you inspect the reader object does it have any other fields populated?  Also, do you have a copy of your connection string that you can post?

Comment: You can also access the database metadata using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema, e.g., `SELECT cu.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS c
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu
ON  
c.TABLE_SCHEMA = cu.TABLE_SCHEMA
AND c.TABLE_NAME = cu.TABLE_NAME
AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'Table'
AND c.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'`

Comment: @marc_s - This is not the OP's own procedure. It is a system one.

Comment: @MartinSmith: you keep learning something new every day! :-) Thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@table_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tableName;
```

Comment: Still no luck. The fact that when I execute the stored procedure in Sql Management Studio and it returns no results concerns me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an issue with your usage of `.AddWithValue()` which may be causing your problem.  See the fix below:

```
public List<string> GetPrimaryKeysForTable(string tableName)
{
    List<string> retVal = new List<string>();
    SqlCommand command = connector.GetCommand("sp_pkeys");
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table_name", tableName);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        retVal.Add(reader[3].ToString());
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

In your example you are attempting to add the `@table_name` as a Type rather than a string.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance it needs to be qualified with the schema? Something like:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table_name", typeof(SqlChars)).Value = "dbo." + tableName;
```

or:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schema", "dbo");
```

Or is there some parm you need to add to tell it the database inside the server?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried giving this a shot. Still no luck. I took the suggestion from one of the comments, and tried the stored procedure from the query analyzer... It didn't return anything either. I then tried your suggestion of using the qualified schema, still no go...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use as below, would you please try it out:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table_name", ("dbo." + tableName));
```

Answer (score 0):

The stored procedure 'sp_pkeys' takes three parameters:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@table_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tableName;
command.Parameters.Add("@table_owner", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tableOwner;
command.Parameters.Add("@table_qualifier", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tableQualifier;
```

It works with just @table_name but could try passing all three to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Question: Does your table have any keys defined?

I have run the slightly modified code below against severa tables in a test DB of my own and it works as expected:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connStr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = "localhost",
            InitialCatalog = "RichTest",
            IntegratedSecurity = true
        };

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr.ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();

            var parents = GetPrimaryKeysForTable(conn, "People");

            Console.WriteLine("Parent Keys:");
            foreach (var p in parents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}", p);
            }
        }
    }

    static IList<string> GetPrimaryKeysForTable(SqlConnection conn, string tableName)
    {
        if (conn == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Value is null", "conn");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tableName)) throw new ArgumentNullException("Value is null or emtpy", "tableName");

        List<String> retVal = new List<string>();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand
        {
            Connection = conn,
            CommandText = "sp_pkeys",
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        })
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table_name", typeof(SqlChars)).Value = tableName;
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                retVal.Add(reader["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString());
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }

}
```